# Flask does not recognize controller when using `url_for()` in HTML form

Tags: python, flask

When trying to implement a basic form I get the following error message: `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'finder.search'. Did you mean 'finder.static' instead?`, the `index.html` page does not even load because of this error.

**Directory**

```
Steam
  SteamFinder
    static
      style.css
    templates
      index.html
      result.html
    __init__.py
    finder.py
  venv
```

****init**.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask.templating import render_template


def create_app():
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from . import finder
    app.register_blueprint(finder.bp)

    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        return render_template("index.html")

    return app
```

**finder.py**

```py
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask.templating import render_template

bp = Blueprint("finder", __name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")

bp.route("/search", methods=["POST"])
def search():
    query = request.form["query"]
    print(query)
    return render_template("result.html")
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/style.css"/>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="{{ url_for('finder.search') }}" method="post">
        <label for="query">Query:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="query" name="query"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `url_for` directly in the template, Jinja cannot process it. You should pass it as a variable to the `render_template` function and use that variable name in the jinja block.

Example:

```
return render_template("index.html", form_action_url=url_for('finder.search'))
```

and the form's action will be:

```
    <form action="{{ form_action_url }}" method="post">
        <label for="query">Query:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="query" name="query"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```